# winmips64 problema with ld instruction

Tags: mips

I have an exercise for my university in which i already wrote a code in mips.
The exercise give us to arrays 2D with some numbers .
I want to load inside some registers the given arrays.

here is the `code` :

```
A: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
.word 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
.word 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
.word 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
.word 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4
.word 0, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
.word 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
.word 0, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7
; 8-by-8 input matrix Β
Β: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
.word 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
.word 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
.word 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0
.word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0
.word 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0
.word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0
.word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7


dmul        $t4,$s1,$s0             ; $t4=i*N       
dadd        $t4,$t4,$s2             ; $t4=(i*N) + j
dsll        $t4,$t4,3                       ; $t4=8 * ((i * N) + j)  
ld          $s3,A($t4)              ; $s3 = A[i][j]
ld          $s4,B($t5)              ; $s4 =B[i][j]
```

The PROBLEM is that the program recognizes the 1st load instruction 
but does not it shows me a red line for the second .
Does anyone knows what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to say `ld  $s4,B($t4)`.  You have not loaded a value into `$t5` which may be what is causing the red line.